# Swift Package Manager Mixed Language Source Files

Tags: ios, swift, package

For some reason when I try to run `swift build` on my `Package.swift` file:import PackageDescription

```
let package = Package(
    name: "mobile-HDISegurado-ios",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/swift-sdk", from: "0.30.0"),
        ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "mobile-HDISegurado-ios",
            dependencies: ["WatsonDeveloperCloud"],
            path: "mobile-HDISegurado-ios",
            exclude: [
                "Config",
                "Public",
                "Resources",
                ]
        )
    ] )
```

I've got the following error:

> error: target at
>   '.../mobile-HDISegurado-ios'
>   contains mixed language source files; feature not supported

More details:

- swift package tools-version: 4.1.0
- project workspace with Cocoapods running.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

SPM now supports mixed language source files, but you may have to separate them into multiple targets.

From [the relevant docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_a_standalone_swift_package_with_xcode):

> Targets can contain Swift, Objective-C/C++, or C/C++ code, but an individual target can’t mix Swift with C-family languages. For example, a Swift package can have two targets, one that contains Objective-C, Objective-C++, and C code, and a second one that contains Swift code.

In practice, you should move your ObjC/C/C++ files into one directory, move your Swift files into another directory, and then modify your Package.swift thus:

```swift
products: [
    .library(
        name: "MyLibrary",
        targets: ["MyLibrarySwift", "MyLibraryObjC"]),
],
.target(name: "MyLibraryObjC",
        path: "Sources/MyLibraryObjC"
),
.target(name: "MyLibrarySwift",
        path: "Sources/MyLibrarySwift"
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `..targets: ["MyLibrarySwift", "MyLibraryObjC"],`?

Comment: you're right, it should. answer updated accordingly. thanks

Comment: i can’t for the life of me figure out what i’m doing wrong – when i write `import MyLibraryObjC` inside a Swift file in `Souces/MyLibrarySwift`, it just says “No such module 'MyLibraryObjC'”

Comment: What is the minimum version(s) of Swift, Swift Package Manager, Xcode, etc. that support these sort of "almost mixed but not quite" types of Swift Packages?

Comment: In my project there is only one single folder which has objective c code, now if I remove this folder & then comment folder reference in bridging header, now I am getting error in all UIKit related files as well which are internally using objective C files.

Answer (score 4):

## 2021 Solution - Xcode 11 and Above

Also if you added Swift files in Objective-C project or workspace, but later removed all Swift files, Xcode still keeps some entries under Build Settings. Check for Swift related options there like the line below:

- SWIFT_INSTALL_OBJC_HEADER
- SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL
- SWIFT_VERSION

If you remove those options, Xcode will not give errors anymore, you can safely install your Package without any hassle.

Tested with:

- swift-tools-version:5.1 and above
- Xcode 11.3 and above

Best.

Answer (score 3):

Are you building iOS project using SPM? Currently SPM doesn't have iOS support. Although, there is a 3rd party tool that fills that gap: https://swiftxcode.github.io/

If you're building for other else then you can't have Swift file and other C family  language file mixed. I had the same problem because there was one Objective-C file inside my target path. All I did was to include the file name inside the `exclude` array.

So, make sure to ignore Objective-C classes if you have one inside "`mobile-HDISegurado-ios`" by passing the file name inside the `exclude` parameter.

Comment: can you provide your package.swift file code as I also have to exclude one objective c class but not able to figure out how to add it in exclude array in package file?

Answer (score 0):

After searching tons of things if you want to use objective c files inside your package then here is my solution

```
   // swift-tools-version: 5.9
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "DMixed",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, making them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "DMixed",
            targets: ["DMixed"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package, defining a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package and products from dependencies.
       
            .target(
                name: "ObjHel",
                 publicHeadersPath: "include"
            ),
            
            .target(
                    name: "DMixed", dependencies: ["ObjHel"]),
                
        .testTarget(
            name: "DMixedTests",
            dependencies: ["DMixed"]),
    ]
)
```

Also my project structure looks like this one

[image: My Project Structure is like this]

And you can use it like this

```
import UIKit
import ObjHel

class TestVCs: UIViewController,WPCustomNumberPadViewControllerDelegate
{
    func didTappedDone(withValue value: String!) {
        print("Abc")
    }
}
```