# How to use a Swift Package (SPM) with Objective code in Objective C project?

Tags: swift, objective-c, package

I've seen mixed reviews about being able to use mixed language projects with SPM. I have a framework that includes Objective-C code. I am using the framework in a mixed language project (Objective-C & Swift); specifically, I need to use it in Objective-C code. I have converted the framework to a Swift Package. The package compiles fine. But I can't get the Objective-C code to recognize my Swift Package. Everything worked fine with the old framework. I've added the new Swift Package to the project.

When I use "@import CalculatorModel;" I get "Module 'CalculatorModel' not found".

I'm trying to import to header into the Objective-C code like this:

```
#import <CalculatorModel/CalculatorModel.h>
```

But, of course, the header isn't found.

Here's my package.swift.

```
let package = Package(
    name: "CalculatorModel",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "CalculatorModel",
            targets: ["CalculatorModel"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "CalculatorModel",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "CalculatorModelTests",
            dependencies: ["CalculatorModel"]),
    ]
)
```

How can I use a Swift Package that includes Objective C in a project with objective-C?

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure that your header file (`CalculatorModel.h`) is public by:

- using `publicHeadersPath` & `headerSearchPath` in your `Package.swift` file:

```
// Package.swift

let package = Package(
    name: "CalculatorModel",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "CalculatorModel",
            targets: ["CalculatorModel"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "CalculatorModel",
            publicHeadersPath: "include",
            cSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("."),
            ]
        ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "CalculatorModelTests",
            dependencies: ["CalculatorModel"]),
    ]
)
```

- adding header file to proper subdirectory:

```
├── README.md
├── Package.swift
└── Sources
    ├── CalculatorModel
    │   └── include
    │       └── CalculatorModel.h
```

2. Try to use `@import` in your header file:

```swift
@import CalculatorModel;
```

Comment: legend. thanks for the `@import` tip!

Comment: +1 regarding `@import`. I also had to create `module.modulemap` and the umbrella header manually (as described [here](https://rderik.com/blog/understanding-objective-c-and-swift-interoperability/)). I didn't use `.headerSearchPath` though, maybe it's the problem.

Comment: Here Is my detailed solution which can help anyone

[SPM issue With Objective-C and Swift]

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77987487/11242101