# Swift Package Mixed Language does not compile

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, objective-c++, swift-package-manager

I have searched lengthely for the solution to my problem, thus before changing strategy, I decide to ask here.

What I need is a mixed language Swift Package using Swift, c++ and Objective-C++. But, I always get the following error when I compile it: `'cstdlib' file not found`. Same error happens for several other standard c++ libraries included in my `TestSwiftPackage.hpp` file.

The project that I am trying to move to Swift Package works perfectly. Thus, I have tried using the same c++ build settings in my `Package.swift`, such as :

- `cSettings` with `headerSearchPath`,
- `cxxSettings` with `unsafeFlags`,
- `linkerSettings` with `linkedLibrary`,
- etc...

But, I keep running into the same compilation bug.

The example project can be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U0dtcd5aaAreg5rs3bQC8JlF8IwnXIM4?usp=sharing

[image: bug]
[image: bug]

Package.swift file:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
   
   name: "TestSwiftPackage",
   products: [
       .library(
           name: "TestSwiftPackage",
           targets: ["TestSwiftPackage"]),
   ],
   dependencies: [],
   targets: [
       .target(
           name: "TestSwiftPackage",
           dependencies: ["TestSwiftPackageC"]
       ),
       .target(
           name: "TestSwiftPackageC",
           dependencies: []
       ),
       .testTarget(
           name: "TestSwiftPackageTests",
           dependencies: ["TestSwiftPackage"]),
   ],
   cLanguageStandard: .gnu11,
   cxxLanguageStandard: .gnucxx11
)
```

Comment: Can you paste your package.swift file contents in the description?

Comment: Hello @Jake, description amended with `package.swift`. Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Hello @AhsokaTano are you able to fix this issue ?

Comment: Here is my solution kindly check
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77987487/11242101