# How to create an SPM package based on ObjC code?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xctest, swift-package-manager

I'd like to create a SwiftPackageManager library based on Objective-C code but I can't seem to grasp what I'm missing.

My latest change to just vanilla ObjC interface .h file inside the include folder was to add an extra C header that includes de ObjC but still had no success. What am I missing?

[image]

The Package.swift file is the default generated one and from what I read it should automatically generate the module map from the include folder.

My swift-tools-version is 5.5

Answer (score 8):

Figured it out.
I added a modulemap that specifies my ObjC header and it worked

[image]

Not sure if it is the correct way to do it since the `include` folder should already do this automatically.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong in your setup, but here is a link to documentation if anybody has similar issue https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md#creating-c-language-targets

Comment: I had a similar issue I don't think we need to touch `module.modulemap` as its for more complicated layouts, my issue was that `publicHeaderPath` searches relative to target and not root, can u share your Package.swift in the question

Comment: @Leonardo Marques Are you able to run tests `MyLibraryTests` ? (I get compiler errors. It looks like `MyLibrary.h` and or module map is not visible to `MyLibraryTests` target? (New symbols I declared in Objective-c are not visible)

Answer (score 2):

So just had the same issue. (my 5 cent)
This is may `Package.swift`:

```
// swift-tools-version: 5.7
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "AlgorithmSDK",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages. , "AlgorithmSDKObjc"
        .library(
            name: "AlgorithmSDK",
            targets: ["AlgorithmSDK","AlgorithmSDKObjc" ]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "AlgorithmSDK",
            dependencies: []),
        
        .testTarget(
            name: "AlgorithmSDKTests",
            dependencies: ["AlgorithmSDK"]),
        
        .target(
            name: "AlgorithmSDKObjc",
            dependencies: [],
            publicHeadersPath:"include"),//<----- This path is relative to the target! (and can be ignored)
        
    ]
)
```

With the structure:

[image]

The [publicHeadersPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/target/publicheaderspath) should be `publicHeadersPath:"include"` OR ignored according to docs (it seems that it takes it relative to target and not the root). I don't think we should touch  `module.modulemap` for such a simple structure

Comment: `publicHeadersPath:"include"` worked for me. I can use the SPM library from my app. However If I create a test target `"AlgorithmSDKObjcTests"`. Test does not compile. Compiler complains because new properties/functions are not visible.

Comment: @nacho4d must admit I did it long time ago and didn't touch it since then (but I do remember that I did write some tests). can u share the exact error?is it  same swift-tools?do u  see the  when u reference your lib inside test target?

Comment: I realized my problem only happens on Categories on Classes that are supposed to be bridged (Like NSURL -> URL). I would appreciate if you could take a look at this new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201998/spm-library-with-objective-c-nsurl-category-not-imported-into-swift-url

Comment: just tried ... seems like working (I changed it a little ), but again I am not really and expert in that part. I will try to push to your repo

Comment: @nacho4d
https://github.com/MikePendo/spm-objc-category/tree/helping_somebody
see if that work

Comment: Here Is my detailed solution which can help anyone

[SPM issue With Objective-C and Swift][1]

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77987487/11242101