# SPM library with Objective-C NSURL category not imported into Swift URL?

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift-package-manager, objective-c-category

I have created a SPM package with a bunch of old Objective-C code (I want to convert some old code *"Objective-C code with a big bridging header"* into *"Objective-C in some SPM packages"*) For most of the cases it works OK except for Objective-C categories like:

```objectivec
@import Foundation;

@interface NSURL (Additions)

@property (copy, readonly) NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *queryParams;

@end
```

**Problem:** Property `queryParams` is NOT available in Swift on `URL` types but only on `NSURL` types. This looks odd to me because when declaring the same category in an App and using the bridging header file, then `queryParams` is also usable from `URL` type too.

```
Tests/URLUtilsTests/URLUtilsTestsSwift.swift:18:31: error: value of type 'URL' has no member 'queryParams'
        let queryParams = url.queryParams
                          ~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
error: fatalError
```

**Question:** What do I need to have `queryParams` in both NSURL and URL while using SPM?

I have created a [repo in GitHub with reproducing problem](https://github.com/nacho4d/spm-objc-category)

This is a screenshot of my entire package:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question in [Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-spm-library-with-objective-c-nsurl-category-is-not-available-in-swift-url-type/65005) and I got the reason why this is not working.

> NSURL and URL are not the same type. The first is a class, the second a struct. ObjC categories or Swift extensions to one do not apply to the other.
>
> There's a runtime "magic" that ties them together, though. It is the URL conformance to ReferenceConvertible 5, and much probably some non-public tricks. But this does not make them the same type.

So the only solution is to have [a special target for swift code](https://github.com/nacho4d/spm-objc-category/pull/2).

```
import URLUtils
extension URL {
    var queryParams: [String: String] {
       (self as NSURL).queryParams
    }
}
```

I have updated my [original repository source code](https://github.com/nacho4d/spm-objc-category) to  and it works ok now!.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to create extension(s) to handle properties that don't exist on Swift types based on the Objective-C equivalents.

In your tests include a .swift extension:

```
// URL+QueryParams.swift

import Foundation

extension URL {
    var queryParams: [String: String] {
        var urlDict = [String: String]()
        guard let query = self.query else { return urlDict }
        let subArray = query.components(separatedBy: "&")
        for element in subArray {
            let urlArray = element.components(separatedBy: "=")
            if urlArray.count < 2 { continue }
            urlDict[urlArray[0]] = urlArray[1]
        }
        return urlDict
    }
}
```

Comment: Query params don't always have anything to the right of `=`, which would make this crash